# Airplane Parking Problem: Optimizing Schedule and Parking Locations(backtracking)

Tags: python, backtracking

I am trying to solve the airplane schedule problem where I receive a list of airplanes that I must park in such a way that when one is parked, it does not interfere with the departure of the others. So far, I have this solution alternative in Python, but I have a problem with the implementation of the backtracking, because the program should print me a dictionary with the location where the airplanes should be parked, but what it prints is an empty dictionary. Sample Input 6 4 5 01 .. == .. 02 03 04 .. 05 06 07 08 .. ## 09 10 11 .. .. 12 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 Sample Output Case 1: Yes 12 09 05 06 02 10

```
def movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if matriz[filas][columnas] == "##":
    return False
  if not matriz[filas][columnas].isdigit():
    return False
  if matriz[filas][columnas] in parqueaderosAsignados.values():
    return False
  return True


def backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if indiceAvion == len(listaEventos):
    return True

  actual = listaEventos[indiceAvion]

  if actual > 0:  # Aterrizando
    for filas in range(len(matriz)):
      for columnas in range(len(matriz[0])):
        if movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados, indiceAvion):
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = matriz[filas][columnas]
          if backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion + 1, parqueaderosAsignados):
            return True
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = ""
  return False


def recibirMatriz():
  parqueaderosAsignados = {}
  numeroAviones, filas, columnas = map(int, input().split())
  if numeroAviones == 0:
    return False

  matriz = []
  for _ in range(filas):
    matriz.append(input().split())

  listaEventos = list(map(int, input().split()))

  for i in range(numeroAviones):
    parqueaderosAsignados[i] = ""

  backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, 0, parqueaderosAsignados)

  # Imprimir el resultado de la asignación de parqueaderos
  print(parqueaderosAsignados.values())

def main():
  while True:
    if not recibirMatriz():
      break


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Sample Output Case 1: Yes 12 09 05 06 02 10
but this is my actual Output: dict_values(['', '', '', '', '', ''])